# python transform in CDAP Tool

Tags: python, etl, cdap

I have trying to create a python transformation in CDAP where I am facing below issue. Request you to kindly check and let me know the update as soon as possible.

Please find the below issue,use case for your reference.

Issue : Configuring stage python is null.

Use case: user is importing data from MYSQL and at python transform we are using sample script and exporting data to File.

Please check the attached screenshot for your reference.

```
  def transform(record, emitter, context):
            if (record['actor_id'] > 0):
                  tax = record['actor_id'] * 10
                   emitter.emit({
                     'actor_id': record['actor_id'],
                     'tax': tax,
                     'total': record['subtotal'] + tax,
                   })
```

actor_id is transformed and processed to the next stage.

Comment: please share the screenshot. its not in the attachment

Comment: Please find the below link for your reference & screenshot https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cdap-issues/qRI_tIOHWRI

Comment: its showing `Caused by: org.python.core.PySyntaxError: null`. have you followed right `indentation`? its showing some error in indentation ```Check results
=============

E111:3:15:indentation is not a multiple of four
E111:4:16:indentation is not a multiple of four
E113:4:16:unexpected indentation
W292:8:18:no newline at end of file
``` please check yourself at http://pep8online.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with

```
def transform(record, emitter, context):
      if (record['actor_id'] > 0):
        tax = record['actor_id'] * 10
        emitter.emit({
           'actor_id': record['actor_id'],
           'tax': tax,
           'total': record['subtotal'] + tax,
         })
```

removed unwanted spaces
[image]